# convert embedded svg to image or canvas (goal is capture screen about selected div container)

Tags: javascript, canvas, svg, jsplumb

Sorry for my English.

I want to draw a diagram with jsPlumb and export captured image.

Jsplumb rendered in svg like this:

```
<svg style="position:absolute;left:457.05px;top:227.65px;z-index:-5;" width="476.9" height="233.7" pointer-events="none" position="absolute" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" class="_jsPlumb_connector ent0 ent1 Line"><path d="M 112.95 178.35 L 363.95 55.35" pointer-events="all" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" style="" fill="none" stroke="black" stroke-width="5"/><path d="M 112.95 178.35 L 363.95 55.35" pointer-events="all" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" style="" fill="none" stroke="blue" stroke-width="3"/></svg>
```

I want to this convert to canvas (which I can convert to image with html2canvas - I try this way: [Google docs](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B0lExpm98uKrZkdOZjBIVFdpV28/edit?usp=sharing)) or direct to image. jsPlumb generate SVG in html and not a file, so I can't use **svgeezy**. I try use canvg, but I can't (bad documentation).

I need a client-side solution or something easier server-side solution.

Example code for jsPlumb: http://jsfiddle.net/WRUra/3/ You just connect div1 to div2 or div3 container and the connector element rendered in svg.

Regards, Zserrbo

Answer (score 0):

If you use canvas mode the connections can easily copied to another canvas.

- make a big canvas copy all canvas connections to the canvas in the
  right place
- for each divs measure its top, left, width, height, and
  get the inner text
- draw rectangles on the big canvas
- draw text inside the rectangles
- export big canvas to image

Comment: I can't use canvas mode for the connection (this: jsPlumb.setRenderMode(jsPlumb.CANVAS);), because the canvas renderer is being removed in (next) jsPlumb version 1.4.0; and the context menu event (right click) doesn't work with Canvas renderer in version 1.3.16.

Comment: If I use jsPlumb.setRenderMode(jsPlumb.CANVAS) method, then I could use easly html2canvas and export to image. I inserted a Google Docs link in my question, where I realize this.